# Sign in to google in app behind the scenes to use private calendar

Tags: cordova, google-api, google-calendar-api, apache-cordova

We're currently programming an app for our company and want to embed private google calendars in it. Since there is no way to access private calendars without signing in to google, we want to create a dummy google account for that and sign in to that account in our app.

Since we don't want to give the password to every employee I would like to sign in to google behind the scenes, if that's possible.

If there are other ways to solve the problem I would also use them, but at the moment, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: No you cannot access google calendars without signing-in google .Because You have to show permissions to every user at the time of  signing-in.

Comment: As I thought, thanks